# setuid programs don't seem to run setuid in TinyCore Linux

Tags: linux, security, setuid

I want to demonstrate the vulnerability of `setuid` programs using the TinyCore Linux live cd. That is, I craft a special program, with special permissions, so that it runs as the owner of the file instead of the executing user. These are my steps:

1. Create a program (see below) with a security hole, compile it in my home system (Ubuntu)
2. Make the program `setuid` and setup the owner of the file, still in Ubuntu
3. Unpack the Tiny Core live cd, copy the vulnerable program inside and `chroot` into it

The problem is the program doesn't seem to run as `setuid`.
Neither in the `chroot` environment, nor in the completed remastered image. 
In Ubuntu it works, but I need it working in Tiny Core. 
The program runs in Tiny Core, but not as the owner,
despite being `setuid`.

The program source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Current time: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  system("date");
  return 0;
}
```

Command to build:

```
gcc -o prog prog.c
```

Make it setuid:

```
sudo chown 1200.1200 prog
sudo chmod 4755 prog
```

Craft a `date` script to demonstrate the vulnerability:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo hello > /tmp/test.txt
ls -l /tmp/test.txt
```

Make the crafted `date` script executable and expose the vulnerability:

```
chmod +x date
PATH=.:$PATH ./prog
```

In Ubuntu, as expected this creates `/tmp/test.txt` with owner 1200. But when I `chroot` to the live cd environment, it does not work there, the executable runs but not as the file owner. If I finish the remastering and create the live cd and boot into it, it does not work there either, even though the file has the right owner and group and permission `4755`. What am I missing?

If you want to create the `chroot` environment, download the 8MB live cd from http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/downloads.html and follow these steps:

```
sudo mount Core-current.iso /mnt
mkdir /tmp/extract
cd /tmp/extract
zcat /mnt/boot/core.gz | sudo cpio -i -H newc -d
```

Copy the vulnerable programs to the `chroot` environment with:

```
sudo cp -a /path/to/prog /tmp/extract/tmp
sudo cp /path/to/date /tmp/extract/tmp
```

`chroot` in there and test the vulnerability:

```
sudo chroot /tmp/extract /bin/sh
su - tc
cd /tmp
PATH=.:$PATH ./prog
```

My end goal of course is to make it work on the live cd itself. It doesn't matter if it doesn't work in `chroot`, it just seems a suitable first test, without having to repack the image and booting into it.

Comment: Does the user owning the setuid program exist within the chrooted environment or only in the "main" environment?

Comment: It doesn't have to. If you try the above steps it should work in any Linux system, and when you run `PATH=.:$PATH ./prog`, the file `/tmp/test.txt` will be created and owned by `uid=1200`, even if it does not exist.

Comment: Is the CD mounted with the nosuid option?

Comment: I don't execute anything from a mounted CD. While remastering the CD, the `chroot` directory is on a regular filesystem not a CD mount. When booting into the completed remastered live CD, the files are on the root filesystem, which is NOT mounted with `nosuid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with `setuid` in TinyCore. However, the simple program in the question is not so simple to exploit in TinyCore.

The `system` call invokes the specified command using `/bin/sh -c`. In TinyCore, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `busybox ash`, which drops `setuid` privileges. So even if you craft a shell script or even a binary that does something malicious and name it `date` to trick the vulnerable program to run it, it will not run as `setuid`. The original program will be running `setuid`, but not the command spawned by `system`.

As a side note, standard `bash` also drops `setuid` privileges when invoked as `/bin/sh`, ever since version 2. However, the vulnerability described in the question can be demonstrated in Debian and its derivatives, as apparently Debian's version of `bash` does not drop privileges. (Obviously there is a good reason for that but I did not research.)

Finally, I could circumvent the behavior of dropping privileges by changing the program to:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // circumvent busybox ash dropping privileges
  uid_t uid = geteuid();
  setreuid(uid, uid);

  printf("Current time: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  system("date");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some security policy (SELinux, AppArmor, ...) is in force, and doesn't allow SUID to non-listed executables? Or is it just that (by sheer sanity) `/tmp` is mounted nosuid?

Comment: The live CD I use is tiny, 8MB to begin with. I doubt it would be that sophisticated, but maybe you're right, I should check on this (not sure how...). As per `/tmp`, I used that only to simplify the question. In my real setup it's in my home directory, not mounted `nosuid`. In fact, the vulnerability test works in the native environment, then I `chroot` into it there it doesn't.